# Why "innerHTML" property from JavaScript can't be an HTML attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, properties, attributes

As we all know to change HTML element's HTML content using JavaScript "innerHTML" property is commonly used. This "innerHTML" property is used on an HTML element object like(`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 5 + 6;`)

My doubt is why the "innerHTML" property can't be used as an attribute in any HTML element?

As per my knowledge and understanding attribute and property have the same semantic meaning.

So, why the below code can not work?

```
<p id="demo" innerHTML="Jumbo"></p>
```

Comment: There's a difference between the HTMLElement in JS and the actual HTML Element. `innerHTML` is a JS DOM property. You can access the attribute using `document.getElementById("demo").getAttribute('innerHTML')` -- Otherwise, just put the text _inside_ the paragraph `<p id="demo">Jumbo</p>`

Comment: I am not sure but innerHTML is like a function first it removes all element's children parses the content string and assigns the resulting nodes as children of the element. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: The JS part is DOM API specification and HTML5 is different specification. 'innerHMTL' attribute is not part of HTML5 specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because not all JavaScript properties on a DOM element equate to attributes.

`.innerHTML` provides a way to get or set the stuff that goes between the start and end tag. So if you want to put stuff there, just put it there:

```
<p id="demo">Jumbo</p>
```

**Edit:** To answer your questions below, the DOM is a conceptual representation of HTML in code (in this case JavaScript), so a DOM element is a JavaScript object that you can use to access and manipulate an HTML element (an element is a portion of an HTML document that starts and ends with a tag, so `<b><span>Hello!</span></b>` contains two elements, a `b` element and a `span` element.

To use `.innerHTML` to get the content of an element, all you need to do is access it in an expression instead of assigning a value to it.

Example:

```js
var d = document.getElementById('myDiv');

console.log(d.innerHTML); // <em>Jumbo</em>
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"><em>Jumbo</em></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you please do me a favour by explaining what exactly do mean by DOM elements and what are they? Also, explain me how to use innerHTML property to get the content in an HTML element? Thank You.

Comment: @user2839497 Updated my answer.