# Javascript - is it possible to change element innerHTML using a command similar to setAttribute

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a function that allows users to change an element property to the value of their choice as follows:

```
<button id = 'element_id'></button>

function change_attribute (attribute, value) {
    element = document.getElementById('element_id')
    element.setAttribute(attribute, value)
}
```

This function works great when editing attributes such as value, id, class, ect... However, when I want to add text to the button such as test button, passing attribute = 'innerHTML', and value = 'Test Button' does not change the text displayed in the button. Am I changing the wrong property or is it not possible to edit the button text using setAttribute?

Comment: text is not an attribute so no...

Comment: You're changing the value/children in the button element, which is not an attribute in this case, so you'll have to directly call `element.innerHTML = 'value'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why "innerHTML" property from JavaScript can't be an HTML attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44073674/why-innerhtml-property-from-javascript-cant-be-an-html-attribute)

Comment: Got it. Thank you everyone! I'll come up with a "work around" then